# angular js default predefined data in $http request

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, post, default

I need a way to add a default data attribute to a http request
I want something like this

```
var app = angular.module('dumbhttp', []);

app.service('dumbhttp', function ($http, $location) {
    this.post = function(url, data){
        data.prePopData = 'sameInfoForEveryRequest';
        return $http.post(url, data);
    };
});
```

this works but it doesn't seem like the right way to do things.
I have to use the service dumbhttp insted of the angulars $http

If this worked it would be great!

```
var app = angular.module('$http', []);

app.service('$http', function ($http, $location) {
    this.post = function(url, data){
        data.prePopData = 'sameInfoForEveryRequest';
        return $http.post(url, data);
    };
});
```

but alas it doesn't :-(

maybe something like this could be the right way to do this

```
$http.setDefaluts.requestData.mykey = 'mydefaultvalue'
```

Im not using this in a RESTful way just heads up, out team uses a different architecture


Thanks in advance!
-James

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use an interceptor:

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(function($q, dependency1, dependency2) {
    return {
     'request': function(config) {
         config.data.prePopData = 'sameInfoForEveryRequest';
         return config;
      }
    };
  });
```

Comment: Yes, you'll need to use Interceptors.  More information (and clarification) can be found [here](https://djds4rce.wordpress.com/2013/08/13/understanding-angular-http-interceptors/).

Comment: This is what im looking for but its not quite working right. when i do ```config.data.prePopData = 'sameInfoForEveryRequest';``` it says data is undefined so i define data and it works but then my data that i pass to  $http gets lost..

Comment: ```TypeError: Cannot set property 'prePopData' of undefined```

Comment: do console.log(config) what are you getting through?

Comment: I Figured it out! 
``` if (typeof config.data !== undefined) {config.data.prePopData = 'sameInfoForEveryRequest';}; ```

Answer (score 0):

You want to take a look at $resource service

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource

Comment: I Could use that. I think $resource is a little heavy for what i'm doing. but if it comes down to it i guess that's what ill do. Thanks